# Knockout SmartTag implementation details

Tags: knockout.js

I wanted to know more about the smart dirty tag implementation in one of the links I came across.

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
<li data-bind="css: { dirty: dirtyFlag.isDirty }">
    <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
    <input data-bind="value: name" />
</li>
```

```
ko.dirtyFlag = function(root) {
    var result = function() {}
    var   _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root));

    result.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
        return  _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
    });

    return result;
};


function Item(id, name) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(this);
}

var ViewModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
        new Item(1, "one"),
        new Item(2, "two"),
        new Item(3, "three")
    ]);

    this.save = function() {
        alert("Sending changes to server: " + ko.toJSON(this.dirtyItems));  
    };

    this.dirtyItems = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.items(), function(item) {
            return item.dirtyFlag.isDirty();
        });
    }, this);

    this.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.dirtyItems().length > 0;
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I made a few changes to the original [post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html)

Here is my new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L16aktah)
I want to know more about the reason for creating a separate function object ko.dirtyFlag.
The blog post says

> making the object a function and adding the computed observable to the function object. This means you have to bind to it as dirtyFlag.isDirty(). When ko.toJS runs, it will just see a plain function and ignore it.

What does this actually mean ?

```
    _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root))
```

Does this statement in the ko.dirtyFlag also re-evaluate all the observables in the creator of the object i.e. Item ?

Also what is the real need for _initialState to be a observable ?

`_initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root))`

The execution fails if the _initialState is not an observable.

A brief note on the actual reason for structuring the code this way is what I really want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making the object a function and adding the computed observable to the function object. This means you have to bind to it as dirtyFlag.isDirty(). When ko.toJS runs, it will just see a plain function and ignore it.

What does this actually mean ?

- That means by making it a function, it will not be included in the info we will be sending to server. This will help us in not sending a lot of unnecessary data to server since Server might not care about IsDirty stuff. Its just the same way toJS ignores all observables related info and just gives you a plain copy of the object.

  _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root));

Does this statement in the ko.dirtyFlag also re-evaluate all the observables in the creator of the object i.e. Item ?

- No, It will only do this on the actual property/object, in this case ITEM. I know the name param "root" is confusing but its not the whole ViewModel.

Also what is the real need for _initialState to be a observable ?

- If you see the actual imprementation, isDirty flag is a computed propety based on initialState.

  result.isDirty = ko.computed(function() {
          return _isInitiallyDirty() || _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
      });

  If its not made an observable, isDirty will not be evaluated every time the object changes.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Very precise and apt reasons. Thank you Krishna.